# chipmunk stack fall effect

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using chipmunk cocos 2d iphone ,in which i have to show stack fall effect when the objects are placed on the edge of other
object.My idea is to develop the effect like "Tower Box " game. I would like to know which properties of shape or body will create effect like "Tower Box " game .please let me know how can I fall that stack.

Comment: I recommend adding a cocos2d tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d provides you with a few preset project options.

One of these is Cocos2d with Box2d, another is Cocos2d with Chipmunk. It is completely up to you which physics engine you use, I have experience with both and personally, would recommend Box2d.

If you create one of these projects, it generates some example code for you, and in the case of Box2d (i haven't used an auto generated chipmunk project), you get a nice little app that spawns loads of boxes and shows them falling with gravity.  You should take a look at the code behind creating the physics bodies on the boxes and adapt it to suit your application (spawn a box at a touch location, perhaps?). You could then add some logic that checks, on collision, the alignment of the falling box with the top of the stack, and either let it continue falling, or use a fixture to attach it to the box below.

For more information about using physics in a cocos2d app, as well as general cocos2d usage, check out this blog, it's what taught me in the beginning: http://www.raywenderlich.com/ [edit: just noticed there are no chipmunk tutorials on there, but the theory should be applicable to both. I found Box2d easier to use than Chipmunk]

What physics effects have you got on the stack so far? What problem have you encountered that made you question the physics properties of the objects?

Answer (score -1):

For these effects you need a physics library. For 2d games [box2d](http://www.box2d.org/) is quite good.

Comment: As you are apparently unaware of the chipmunk physics library, I will simply let you know that the cocos2d for iPhone framework comes with the chipmunk physics engine along side it, hence the statement "I am using the chipmunk cocos 2d iphone"